# Flattening a List within a List R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, tidyverse

I have a list within a list that I would like to flatten to put into a data frame.
here is the list

```
dput(data)
list(list(data = list(list(ticker = "MS", tradeDate = "2019-03-01", 
    assetType = 3L, priorCls = 41.98, pxAtmIv = 42.59, mktCap = 73261L, 
    cVolu = 24699L, cOi = 323963L, pVolu = 19573L, pOi = 463409L, 
    orFcst20d = 23.126, orIvFcst20d = 24.511, orFcstInf = 23.83, 
    orIvXern20d = 23.02, orIvXernInf = 24.64, iv200Ma = 24.75, 
    atmIvM1 = 22.898, atmFitIvM1 = 22.635, atmFcstIvM1 = 23.126, 
    dtExM1 = 15L, atmIvM2 = 24.356, atmFitIvM2 = 24.055, atmFcstIvM2 = 23.672, 
    dtExM2 = 78L, atmIvM3 = 23.993, atmFitIvM3 = 24.092, atmFcstIvM3 = 23.662, 
    dtExM3 = 113L, atmIvM4 = 23.485, atmFitIvM4 = 24.383, atmFcstIvM4 = 23.813, 
    dtExM4 = 141L, iRate5wk = 2.45, iRateLt = 2.51, px1kGam = 204.42, 
    volOfVol = 0.0545, volOfIvol = 0.0443, slope = 2.478806, 
    slopeInf = 3.76504, slopeFcst = 3.00511, slopeFcstInf = 4.3456, 
    deriv = 0.0825, derivInf = 0.0804, derivFcst = 0.0963, derivFcstInf = 0.0993, 
    mktWidthVol = 0.817, mktWidthVolInf = 0.654, cAddPrem = 0L, 
    pAddPrem = 0L, rip = 0.57161, ivEarnReturn = 0L, fcstR2 = 0.318, 
    fcstR2Imp = 0.264, hiHedge = 0L, loHedge = 0L, stkVolu = 11051511L, 
    avgOptVolu20d = 35962.75, sector = "XLF Security Brokers  Dealers  and Flotation Companies42936", 
    orHv1d = 21.94, orHv5d = 18.87, orHv10d = 22.51, orHv20d = 23.27, 
    orHv60d = 34.79, orHv90d = 34.63, orHv120d = 33.07, orHv252d = 29.61, 
    orHv500d = 26.74, orHv1000d = 28.21, clsHv5d = 12.96, clsHv10d = 19.89, 
    clsHv20d = 21.2, clsHv60d = 31.03, clsHv90d = 30.24, clsHv120d = 29.61, 
    clsHv252d = 27.07, clsHv500d = 24.41, clsHv1000d = 27.16, 
    iv20d = 22.78, iv30d = 23.03, iv60d = 24.08, iv90d = 24.22, 
    iv6m = 24.18, clsPx1w = 41.79, stkPxChng1wk = 1.91, clsPx1m = 42.79, 
    stkPxChng1m = -0.47, clsPx6m = 48.1543, stkPxChng6m = -11.56, 
    clsPx1y = 53.1643, stkPxChng1y = -19.89, divFreq = 91L, divYield = 2.8, 
    divGrwth = 0L, divDate = "2019-04-29", divAmt = 0.3, nextErn = "0000-00-00", 
    nextErnTod = 900L, lastErn = "2019-01-17", lastErnTod = 2L, 
    absAvgErnMv = 2.3636, impliedIee = 1.6005, daysToNextErn = 0L, 
    tkOver = 0L, etfIncl = "", bestEtf = "XLF", sectorName = "Diversified Financials", 
    correlSpy1m = 0.35, correlSpy1y = 0.93, correlEtf1m = 0.68, 
    correlEtf1y = 0.94, beta1m = 0.02, beta1y = 0.08, ivPctile1m = 32L, 
    ivPctile1y = 53L, ivPctileSpy = 62L, ivPctileEtf = 99L, ivStdvMean = 0.08, 
    ivStdv1y = 4.46, ivSpyRatio = 1.97, ivSpyRatioAvg1m = 1.82, 
    ivSpyRatioAvg1y = 1.85, ivSpyRatioStdv1y = 6.13, ivEtfRatio = 1.58, 
    ivEtfRatioAvg1m = 1.51, ivEtfRatioAvg1y = 1.4, ivEtFratioStdv1y = 6.62, 
    ivHvXernRatio = 1.02, ivHvXernRatio1m = 0.95, ivHvXernRatio1y = 0.9, 
    ivHvXernRatioStdv1y = 3L, etfIvHvXernRatio = 0.89, etfIvHvXernRatio1m = 0.91, 
    etfIvHvXernRatio1y = 0.91, etfIvHvXernRatioStdv1y = 0.02, 
    slopepctile = 44.84, slopeavg1m = 2.92, slopeavg1y = 2.92, 
    slopeStdv1y = 0.56, etfSlopeRatio = 0.54, etfSlopeRatioAvg1m = 0.55, 
    etfSlopeRatioAvg1y = 0.55, etfSlopeRatioAvgStdv1y = 0.11, 
    impliedR2 = 0.388, contango = -0.034720401163213, nextDiv = 0.3, 
    impliedNextDiv = 0.205366, annActDiv = 1.2, annIdiv = 0.841768, 
    borrow30 = 1.93096082657576, borrow2yr = 1.89570486545563, 
    error = 0.00268254225375131, confidence = 90.0555968284607, 
    updatedAt = "2019-03-01 15:06:29")), included = list(list(
    type = list("earn"), data = list(list(ticker = "MS", tradeDate = "2019-03-01", 
        pxCls = 41.98, wksNextErn = 6L, nextErnTod = 900L, ernMnth = 4L, 
        avgOptVolu20d = 35963L, oi = 787372L, atmIvM1 = 22.8975, 
        dtExM1 = 15L, atmIvM2 = 24.3557, dtExm2 = 78L, atmIvM3 = 23.9932, 
        dtExM3 = 113L, atmIvM4 = 23.4853, dtExM4 = 141L, straPxM1 = 1.53, 
        straPxM2 = 3.89, smoothStraPxM1 = 1.55, smoothStrPxM2 = 3.85, 
        fcstStraPxM1 = 1.57, fcstStraPxM2 = 3.74, loStrikeM1 = 42.5, 
        hiStrikeM1 = 42.5, loStrikeM2 = 43L, hiStrikeM2 = 43L, 
        ernDate1 = "1/17/2019", ernDate2 = "10/16/2018", ernDate3 = "7/18/2018", 
        ernDate4 = "4/18/2018", ernDate5 = "1/18/2018", ernDate6 = "10/17/2017", 
        ernDate7 = "7/19/2017", ernDate8 = "4/19/2017", ernDate9 = "1/17/2017", 
        ernDate10 = "10/19/2016", ernDate11 = "7/20/2016", ernDate12 = "1/19/2016", 
        ernMv1 = -4.4055, ernMv2 = 5.6821, ernMv3 = 2.806, ernMv4 = 0.0376, 
        ernMv5 = 0.8853, ernMv6 = 0.3678, ernMv7 = 3.2787, ernMv8 = 2.0141, 
        ernMv9 = -3.7891, ernMv10 = 1.8874, ernMv11 = 2.0929, 
        ernMv12 = 1.1166, ernStraPct1 = 4.4196, ernStraPct2 = 3.3479, 
        ernStraPct3 = 2.7417, ernStraPct4 = 2.7022, ernStraPct5 = 2.4245, 
        ernStraPct6 = 3.1256, ernStraPct7 = 2.5133, ernStraPct8 = 2.9624, 
        ernStraPct9 = 3.3303, ernStraPct10 = 2.8828, ernStraPct11 = 5.7447, 
        ernStraPct12 = 10.073, ernEffct1 = 0L, ernEffct2 = 2.4334, 
        ernEffct3 = 1.6096, ernEffct4 = 1.6449, ernEffct5 = 1.6363, 
        ernEffct6 = 1.3593, ernEffct7 = 1.4688, ernEffct8 = 0.98, 
        ernEffct9 = 1.8458, ernEffct10 = 1.0206, ernEffct11 = 1.1964, 
        ernEffct12 = 1.4761, orHv5d = 18.87, orHv10d = 22.51, 
        orHv20d = 23.27, orHv60d = 34.79, orHv90d = 34.63, orHv120d = 33.07, 
        orHv252d = 29.61, orHv500d = 26.74, orHv1000d = 28.21, 
        orHvXern5d = 18.87, orHvXern10d = 22.51, orHvXern20d = 23.27, 
        orHvXern60d = 34.79, orHvXern90d = 34.63, orHvXern120d = 32.46, 
        orHvXern252d = 29.16, orHvXern500d = 26.42, orHvXern1000d = 27.95, 
        clsHv5d = 12.96, clsHv10d = 19.89, clsHv20d = 21.2, clsHv60d = 31.03, 
        clsHv90d = 30.24, clsHv120d = 29.61, clsHv252d = 27.07, 
        clsHv500d = 24.41, clsHv1000d = 27.16, clsHvXern5d = 12.96, 
        clsHvXern10d = 19.89, clsHvXern20d = 21.2, clsHvXern60d = 31.03, 
        clsHvXern90d = 30.24, clsHvXern120d = 28.32, clsHvXern252d = 26.26, 
        clsHvXern500d = 23.82, clsHvXern1000d = 26.82, iv10d = 22.66, 
        iv20d = 22.78, iv30d = 23.03, iv60d = 24.77, iv90d = 24.22, 
        iv6m = 24.18, iv1yr = 24.6, orIvXern20d = 23.02, orIvXernInf = 24.64, 
        slope = 2.4788, fcstSlope = 3.0051, fcstErnEffct = 1.6232, 
        absAvgErnMv = 2.3636, ernMvStdv = 1.628, impliedEe = 1.6005, 
        impErnMv = 2.6, impMth2ErnMv = 2.6, fairVol90d = 23.893, 
        fairXieeVol90d = 24.042, fairMth2XieeVol90d = 23.0232, 
        impErnMv90d = 0.73, impErnMvMth290d = 0.47, exErnIv10d = 22.66, 
        exErnIv20d = 22.76, exErnIv30d = 22.39, exErnIv60d = 22.64, 
        exErnIv90d = 22.36, exErnIv6m = 22.49, exErnIv1yr = 23.02, 
        updatedAt = "2019-03-01 03:06:29"))))), list(data = list(
    list(ticker = "GS", tradeDate = "2019-03-01", assetType = 3L, 
        priorCls = 196.7, pxAtmIv = 198.41, mktCap = 73803L, 
        cVolu = 28845L, cOi = 174999L, pVolu = 14756L, pOi = 190442L, 
        orFcst20d = 22.138, orIvFcst20d = 23.209, orFcstInf = 22.8, 
        orIvXern20d = 22.23, orIvXernInf = 21.94, iv200Ma = 22.54, 
        atmIvM1 = 21.428, atmFitIvM1 = 21.859, atmFcstIvM1 = 22.138, 
        dtExM1 = 15L, atmIvM2 = 23.522, atmFitIvM2 = 23.623, 
        atmFcstIvM2 = 22.81, dtExM2 = 78L, atmIvM3 = 23.152, 
        atmFitIvM3 = 23.165, atmFcstIvM3 = 22.753, dtExM3 = 113L, 
        atmIvM4 = 23.567, atmFitIvM4 = 23.661, atmFcstIvM4 = 22.965, 
        dtExM4 = 141L, iRate5wk = 2.45, iRateLt = 2.51, px1kGam = 4057.42, 
        volOfVol = 0.0581, volOfIvol = 0.0451, slope = 2.323271, 
        slopeInf = 3.71721, slopeFcst = 3.04759, slopeFcstInf = 4.46038, 
        deriv = 0.0787, derivInf = 0.0745, derivFcst = 0.0802, 
        derivFcstInf = 0.0852, mktWidthVol = 0.76, mktWidthVolInf = 0.365, 
        cAddPrem = 0L, pAddPrem = 0L, rip = 2.6733, ivEarnReturn = 0L, 
        fcstR2 = 0.2547, fcstR2Imp = 0.2518, hiHedge = 0L, loHedge = 0L, 
        stkVolu = 2748881L, avgOptVolu20d = 32366.5, sector = "XLF Security Brokers  Dealers  and Flotation Companies42934", 
        orHv1d = 13.39, orHv5d = 16.59, orHv10d = 21.44, orHv20d = 21.23, 
        orHv60d = 33.88, orHv90d = 34.83, orHv120d = 32.29, orHv252d = 27.44, 
        orHv500d = 25.33, orHv1000d = 24.85, clsHv5d = 10.78, 
        clsHv10d = 18.97, clsHv20d = 18.47, clsHv60d = 32.95, 
        clsHv90d = 34.22, clsHv120d = 31.52, clsHv252d = 26.11, 
        clsHv500d = 23.88, clsHv1000d = 24.19, iv20d = 21.73, 
        iv30d = 22.04, iv60d = 24.28, iv90d = 23.39, iv6m = 23.5, 
        clsPx1w = 195.2117, stkPxChng1wk = 1.64, clsPx1m = 201.6656, 
        stkPxChng1m = -1.61, clsPx6m = 235.8982, stkPxChng6m = -15.89, 
        clsPx1y = 252.9804, stkPxChng1y = -21.57, divFreq = 91L, 
        divYield = 1.6, divGrwth = 0L, divDate = "2019-05-30", 
        divAmt = 0.8, nextErn = "0000-00-00", nextErnTod = 900L, 
        lastErn = "2019-01-16", lastErnTod = 2L, absAvgErnMv = 2.6987, 
        impliedIee = 2.3536, daysToNextErn = 0L, tkOver = 0L, 
        etfIncl = "", bestEtf = "XLF", sectorName = "Diversified Financials", 
        correlSpy1m = 0.45, correlSpy1y = 0.96, correlEtf1m = 0.7, 
        correlEtf1y = 0.94, beta1m = 0.04, beta1y = 0.88, ivPctile1m = 41L, 
        ivPctile1y = 59L, ivPctileSpy = 82L, ivPctileEtf = 100L, 
        ivStdvMean = 0.18, ivStdv1y = 4.73, ivSpyRatio = 1.89, 
        ivSpyRatioAvg1m = 1.74, ivSpyRatioAvg1y = 1.77, ivSpyRatioStdv1y = 5.86, 
        ivEtfRatio = 1.51, ivEtfRatioAvg1m = 1.44, ivEtfRatioAvg1y = 1.34, 
        ivEtFratioStdv1y = 6.33, ivHvXernRatio = 1.07, ivHvXernRatio1m = 1.02, 
        ivHvXernRatio1y = 0.98, ivHvXernRatioStdv1y = 2.58, etfIvHvXernRatio = 0.94, 
        etfIvHvXernRatio1m = 0.94, etfIvHvXernRatio1y = 0.97, 
        etfIvHvXernRatioStdv1y = 0.03, slopepctile = 53.97, slopeavg1m = 2.93, 
        slopeavg1y = 2.68, slopeStdv1y = 0.77, etfSlopeRatio = 0.53, 
        etfSlopeRatioAvg1m = 0.55, etfSlopeRatioAvg1y = 0.51, 
        etfSlopeRatioAvgStdv1y = 0.15, impliedR2 = 0.3442, contango = 0.211597932502627, 
        nextDiv = 0.8, impliedNextDiv = 0.455907, annActDiv = 3.2, 
        annIdiv = 1.10991, borrow30 = 2.05527078360319, borrow2yr = 1.78055688738823, 
        error = 0.00312121410388499, confidence = 97.6749777793884, 
        updatedAt = "2019-03-01 15:04:22")), included = list(
    list(type = list("earn"), data = list(list(ticker = "GS", 
        tradeDate = "2019-03-01", pxCls = 196.7, wksNextErn = 6L, 
        nextErnTod = 900L, ernMnth = 4L, avgOptVolu20d = 32367L, 
        oi = 365441L, atmIvM1 = 21.4282, dtExM1 = 15L, atmIvM2 = 23.5218, 
        dtExm2 = 78L, atmIvM3 = 23.1523, dtExM3 = 113L, atmIvM4 = 23.5669, 
        dtExM4 = 141L, straPxM1 = 7.05, straPxM2 = 17.62, smoothStraPxM1 = 6.79, 
        smoothStrPxM2 = 17.3, fcstStraPxM1 = 7.07, fcstStraPxM2 = 16.82, 
        loStrikeM1 = 197.5, hiStrikeM1 = 197.5, loStrikeM2 = 200L, 
        hiStrikeM2 = 200L, ernDate1 = "1/16/2019", ernDate2 = "10/16/2018", 
        ernDate3 = "7/17/2018", ernDate4 = "4/17/2018", ernDate5 = "1/17/2018", 
        ernDate6 = "10/17/2017", ernDate7 = "7/18/2017", ernDate8 = "4/18/2017", 
        ernDate9 = "1/18/2017", ernDate10 = "10/18/2016", ernDate11 = "7/19/2016", 
        ernDate12 = "4/19/2016", ernMv1 = 9.5437, ernMv2 = 3.0109, 
        ernMv3 = -0.1815, ernMv4 = -1.648, ernMv5 = -1.861, ernMv6 = -2.6071, 
        ernMv7 = -2.5953, ernMv8 = -4.7158, ernMv9 = -0.6151, 
        ernMv10 = 2.1479, ernMv11 = -1.1755, ernMv12 = 2.2827, 
        ernStraPct1 = 4.0428, ernStraPct2 = 3.5101, ernStraPct3 = 2.5044, 
        ernStraPct4 = 2.7463, ernStraPct5 = 2.7089, ernStraPct6 = 2.5174, 
        ernStraPct7 = 2.8252, ernStraPct8 = 3.0027, ernStraPct9 = 3.269, 
        ernStraPct10 = 2.565, ernStraPct11 = 5.0717, ernStraPct12 = 6.0423, 
        ernEffct1 = 3.134, ernEffct2 = 2.0023, ernEffct3 = 1.2008, 
        ernEffct4 = 1.4303, ernEffct5 = 1.9408, ernEffct6 = 2.2619, 
        ernEffct7 = 1.6163, ernEffct8 = 1.9099, ernEffct9 = 1.022, 
        ernEffct10 = 1.046, ernEffct11 = 1.1364, ernEffct12 = 2.0767, 
        orHv5d = 16.59, orHv10d = 21.44, orHv20d = 21.23, orHv60d = 33.88, 
        orHv90d = 34.83, orHv120d = 32.29, orHv252d = 27.44, 
        orHv500d = 25.33, orHv1000d = 24.85, orHvXern5d = 16.59, 
        orHvXern10d = 21.44, orHvXern20d = 21.23, orHvXern60d = 31.13, 
        orHvXern90d = 33.12, orHvXern120d = 30.63, orHvXern252d = 26.45, 
        orHvXern500d = 24.49, orHvXern1000d = 24.31, clsHv5d = 10.78, 
        clsHv10d = 18.97, clsHv20d = 18.47, clsHv60d = 32.95, 
        clsHv90d = 34.22, clsHv120d = 31.52, clsHv252d = 26.11, 
        clsHv500d = 23.88, clsHv1000d = 24.19, clsHvXern5d = 10.78, 
        clsHvXern10d = 18.97, clsHvXern20d = 18.47, clsHvXern60d = 26.81, 
        clsHvXern90d = 30.36, clsHvXern120d = 27.82, clsHvXern252d = 24.15, 
        clsHvXern500d = 22.48, clsHvXern1000d = 23.5, iv10d = 21.56, 
        iv20d = 21.73, iv30d = 22.04, iv60d = 24.41, iv90d = 23.39, 
        iv6m = 23.5, iv1yr = 22.95, orIvXern20d = 22.23, orIvXernInf = 21.94, 
        slope = 2.3233, fcstSlope = 3.0476, fcstErnEffct = 1.5724, 
        absAvgErnMv = 2.6987, ernMvStdv = 2.3509, impliedEe = 2.3536, 
        impErnMv = 4.26, impMth2ErnMv = 4.26, fairVol90d = 24.7949, 
        fairXieeVol90d = 24.4598, fairMth2XieeVol90d = 22.2471, 
        impErnMv90d = 1.99, impErnMvMth290d = 1.27, exErnIv10d = 21.56, 
        exErnIv20d = 22.3, exErnIv30d = 21.88, exErnIv60d = 22.7, 
        exErnIv90d = 22.25, exErnIv6m = 22.15, exErnIv1yr = 21.73, 
        updatedAt = "2019-03-01 03:04:22"))))), list(data = list(
    list(ticker = "MPC", tradeDate = "2019-03-01", assetType = 3L, 
        priorCls = 62.01, pxAtmIv = 62.47, mktCap = 43158L, cVolu = 9612L, 
        cOi = 77447L, pVolu = 5031L, pOi = 54939L, orFcst20d = 25.766, 
        orIvFcst20d = 26.471, orFcstInf = 27.55, orIvXern20d = 25.57, 
        orIvXernInf = 25.15, iv200Ma = 32.24, atmIvM1 = 24.752, 
        atmFitIvM1 = 25.368, atmFcstIvM1 = 25.766, dtExM1 = 15L, 
        atmIvM2 = 27.138, atmFitIvM2 = 26.747, atmFcstIvM2 = 27.113, 
        dtExM2 = 78L, atmIvM3 = 25.689, atmFitIvM3 = 26.317, 
        atmFcstIvM3 = 27.103, dtExM3 = 113L, atmIvM4 = 26.016, 
        atmFitIvM4 = 26.12, atmFcstIvM4 = 27.11, dtExM4 = 141L, 
        iRate5wk = 2.45, iRateLt = 2.51, px1kGam = 546.58, volOfVol = 0.0962, 
        volOfIvol = 0.0351, slope = 3.198042, slopeInf = 4.27906, 
        slopeFcst = 3.01984, slopeFcstInf = 4.52443, deriv = 0.0796, 
        derivInf = 0.0777, derivFcst = 0.076, derivFcstInf = 0.1254, 
        mktWidthVol = 1.237, mktWidthVolInf = 0.734, cAddPrem = 0L, 
        pAddPrem = 0L, rip = 0.98722, ivEarnReturn = 0L, fcstR2 = 0.5081, 
        fcstR2Imp = 0.4618, hiHedge = 0L, loHedge = 0L, stkVolu = 5892284L, 
        avgOptVolu20d = 10425.4, sector = "XOP Petroleum Refineries42943", 
        orHv1d = 34.64, orHv5d = 22.78, orHv10d = 22.42, orHv20d = 32.58, 
        orHv60d = 38.49, orHv90d = 40.25, orHv120d = 38.77, orHv252d = 35.24, 
        orHv500d = 30.27, orHv1000d = 36.37, clsHv5d = 16.37, 
        clsHv10d = 17.88, clsHv20d = 26.49, clsHv60d = 31.52, 
        clsHv90d = 34.74, clsHv120d = 34.05, clsHv252d = 31.87, 
        clsHv500d = 27.1, clsHv1000d = 33.22, iv20d = 25.52, 
        iv30d = 25.58, iv60d = 26.07, iv90d = 26.61, iv6m = 26.4, 
        clsPx1w = 65.02, stkPxChng1wk = -3.92, clsPx1m = 64.7985, 
        stkPxChng1m = -3.59, clsPx6m = 81.0285, stkPxChng6m = -22.9, 
        clsPx1y = 63.058, stkPxChng1y = -0.93, divFreq = 91L, 
        divYield = 3.4, divGrwth = 0L, divDate = "2019-05-13", 
        divAmt = 0.53, nextErn = "0000-00-00", nextErnTod = 900L, 
        lastErn = "2019-02-07", lastErnTod = 2L, absAvgErnMv = 3.2899, 
        impliedIee = 2.1494, daysToNextErn = 0L, tkOver = 0L, 
        etfIncl = "", bestEtf = "XOP", sectorName = "", correlSpy1m = 0.71, 
        correlSpy1y = 0.55, correlEtf1m = 0.73, correlEtf1y = 0.71, 
        beta1m = 0.02, beta1y = 0.47, ivPctile1m = 59L, ivPctile1y = 40L, 
        ivPctileSpy = 48L, ivPctileEtf = 15L, ivStdvMean = -0.07, 
        ivStdv1y = 11.02, ivSpyRatio = 2.2, ivSpyRatioAvg1m = 2.03, 
        ivSpyRatioAvg1y = 2.06, ivSpyRatioStdv1y = 6.83, ivEtfRatio = 0.87, 
        ivEtfRatioAvg1m = 0.88, ivEtfRatioAvg1y = 0.89, ivEtFratioStdv1y = 4.62, 
        ivHvXernRatio = 1.07, ivHvXernRatio1m = 0.95, ivHvXernRatio1y = 0.83, 
        ivHvXernRatioStdv1y = 3.98, etfIvHvXernRatio = 1.05, 
        etfIvHvXernRatio1m = 0.99, etfIvHvXernRatio1y = 0.93, 
        etfIvHvXernRatioStdv1y = 0.08, slopepctile = 95.63, slopeavg1m = 3.13, 
        slopeavg1y = 2.35, slopeStdv1y = 0.77, etfSlopeRatio = 1.29, 
        etfSlopeRatioAvg1m = 1.19, etfSlopeRatioAvg1y = 0.9, 
        etfSlopeRatioAvgStdv1y = 0.29, impliedR2 = 0.4739, contango = 0.276703387498856, 
        nextDiv = 0.53, impliedNextDiv = 0.323503, annActDiv = 2.14524, 
        annIdiv = 1.22879, borrow30 = 2.76241712272167, borrow2yr = 1.51972714811563, 
        error = 0.00337655801558867, confidence = 93.5644745826721, 
        updatedAt = "2019-03-01 15:06:26")), included = list(
    list(type = list("earn"), data = list(list(ticker = "MPC", 
        tradeDate = "2019-03-01", pxCls = 62.01, wksNextErn = 8L, 
        nextErnTod = 900L, ernMnth = 5L, avgOptVolu20d = 10425L, 
        oi = 132386L, atmIvM1 = 24.752, dtExM1 = 15L, atmIvM2 = 27.1377, 
        dtExm2 = 78L, atmIvM3 = 25.689, dtExM3 = 113L, atmIvM4 = 26.0161, 
        dtExM4 = 141L, straPxM1 = 2.5, straPxM2 = 6.5, smoothStraPxM1 = 2.45, 
        smoothStrPxM2 = 6.36, fcstStraPxM1 = 2.54, fcstStraPxM2 = 6.35, 
        loStrikeM1 = 62.5, hiStrikeM1 = 62.5, loStrikeM2 = 62.5, 
        hiStrikeM2 = 62.5, ernDate1 = "2/7/2019", ernDate2 = "11/1/2018", 
        ernDate3 = "7/26/2018", ernDate4 = "4/30/2018", ernDate5 = "2/1/2018", 
        ernDate6 = "10/26/2017", ernDate7 = "7/27/2017", ernDate8 = "4/27/2017", 
        ernDate9 = "2/1/2017", ernDate10 = "10/27/2016", ernDate11 = "7/28/2016", 
        ernDate12 = "2/3/2016", ernMv1 = -4.7405, ernMv2 = 0.8943, 
        ernMv3 = 7.2805, ernMv4 = -8.0069, ernMv5 = -0.8373, 
        ernMv6 = 1.4706, ernMv7 = 0.8803, ernMv8 = 2.8629, ernMv9 = -0.7076, 
        ernMv10 = -3.2761, ernMv11 = 0.8987, ernMv12 = -7.6235, 
        ernStraPct1 = 4.5792, ernStraPct2 = 7.3844, ernStraPct3 = 6.1646, 
        ernStraPct4 = 5.9654, ernStraPct5 = 4.883, ernStraPct6 = 5.1241, 
        ernStraPct7 = 5.2302, ernStraPct8 = 5.7913, ernStraPct9 = 6.8721, 
        ernStraPct10 = 7.7218, ernStraPct11 = 8.7279, ernStraPct12 = 8.6632, 
        ernEffct1 = 2.4327, ernEffct2 = 1.4501, ernEffct3 = 2.6508, 
        ernEffct4 = 3.0809, ernEffct5 = 1.709, ernEffct6 = 1.6473, 
        ernEffct7 = 1.8643, ernEffct8 = 1.4013, ernEffct9 = 1.3424, 
        ernEffct10 = 1.4696, ernEffct11 = 1.473, ernEffct12 = 2.3858, 
        orHv5d = 22.78, orHv10d = 22.42, orHv20d = 32.58, orHv60d = 38.49, 
        orHv90d = 40.25, orHv120d = 38.77, orHv252d = 35.24, 
        orHv500d = 30.27, orHv1000d = 36.37, orHvXern5d = 22.78, 
        orHvXern10d = 22.42, orHvXern20d = 24.74, orHvXern60d = 36.83, 
        orHvXern90d = 38.89, orHvXern120d = 37.67, orHvXern252d = 33.53, 
        orHvXern500d = 29L, orHvXern1000d = 35.17, clsHv5d = 16.37, 
        clsHv10d = 17.88, clsHv20d = 26.49, clsHv60d = 31.52, 
        clsHv90d = 34.74, clsHv120d = 34.05, clsHv252d = 31.87, 
        clsHv500d = 27.1, clsHv1000d = 33.22, clsHvXern5d = 16.37, 
        clsHvXern10d = 17.88, clsHvXern20d = 20.98, clsHvXern60d = 30.32, 
        clsHvXern90d = 34.37, clsHvXern120d = 33.75, clsHvXern252d = 29.78, 
        clsHvXern500d = 25.78, clsHvXern1000d = 32.28, iv10d = 24.33, 
        iv20d = 25.52, iv30d = 25.58, iv60d = 26.28, iv90d = 26.61, 
        iv6m = 26.4, iv1yr = 26.62, orIvXern20d = 25.57, orIvXernInf = 25.15, 
        slope = 3.198, fcstSlope = 3.0198, fcstErnEffct = 1.8897, 
        absAvgErnMv = 3.2899, ernMvStdv = 2.7764, impliedEe = 2.1494, 
        impErnMv = 4.34, impMth2ErnMv = 4.34, fairVol90d = 27.1377, 
        fairXieeVol90d = 26.7474, fairMth2XieeVol90d = 25.5777, 
        impErnMv90d = 1.16, impErnMvMth290d = 0.8, exErnIv10d = 24.33, 
        exErnIv20d = 24.87, exErnIv30d = 25.51, exErnIv60d = 25.57, 
        exErnIv90d = 25.4, exErnIv6m = 24.54, exErnIv1yr = 25.31, 
        updatedAt = "2019-03-01 03:06:26"))))), list(data = list(
    list(ticker = "ORCL", tradeDate = "2019-03-01", assetType = 3L, 
        priorCls = 52.13, pxAtmIv = 52.64, mktCap = 217909L, 
        cVolu = 17659L, cOi = 188341L, pVolu = 11012L, pOi = 178180L, 
        orFcst20d = 16.742, orIvFcst20d = 16.099, orFcstInf = 15.5, 
        orIvXern20d = 16.53, orIvXernInf = 14.56, iv200Ma = 20.18, 
        atmIvM1 = 15.541, atmFitIvM1 = 16.139, atmFcstIvM1 = 16.742, 
        dtExM1 = 15L, atmIvM2 = 18.764, atmFitIvM2 = 19.186, 
        atmFcstIvM2 = 17.348, dtExM2 = 78L, atmIvM3 = 19.66, 
        atmFitIvM3 = 20.01, atmFcstIvM3 = 17.669, dtExM3 = 113L, 
        atmIvM4 = 19.381, atmFitIvM4 = 18.969, atmFcstIvM4 = 17.241, 
        dtExM4 = 204L, iRate5wk = 2.45, iRateLt = 2.52, px1kGam = 165.3, 
        volOfVol = 0.0701, volOfIvol = 0.0418, slope = 3.886953, 
        slopeInf = 4.60893, slopeFcst = 4.32527, slopeFcstInf = 4.62464, 
        deriv = 0.0746, derivInf = 0.0801, derivFcst = 0.1015, 
        derivFcstInf = 0.0999, mktWidthVol = 0.953, mktWidthVolInf = 0.548, 
        cAddPrem = 0L, pAddPrem = 0L, rip = 0.50835, ivEarnReturn = 0L, 
        fcstR2 = 0.3281, fcstR2Imp = 0.2166, hiHedge = 0L, loHedge = 0L, 
        stkVolu = 12703571L, avgOptVolu20d = 15393.1, sector = "XLK Prepackaged Software42901", 
        orHv1d = 9.71, orHv5d = 10L, orHv10d = 12.71, orHv20d = 14.46, 
        orHv60d = 27.63, orHv90d = 27.37, orHv120d = 26.23, orHv252d = 24.55, 
        orHv500d = 21.9, orHv1000d = 20.98, clsHv5d = 6.87, clsHv10d = 7.05, 
        clsHv20d = 11.41, clsHv60d = 24.43, clsHv90d = 25.01, 
        clsHv120d = 23.75, clsHv252d = 24.19, clsHv500d = 22.22, 
        clsHv1000d = 21.11, iv20d = 23.41, iv30d = 23.5, iv60d = 19.91, 
        iv90d = 19.09, iv6m = 19.45, clsPx1w = 52.48, stkPxChng1wk = 0.3, 
        clsPx1m = 50.36, stkPxChng1m = 4.53, clsPx6m = 48.1944, 
        stkPxChng6m = 9.22, clsPx1y = 48.9202, stkPxChng1y = 7.6, 
        divFreq = 91L, divYield = 1.4, divGrwth = 0L, divDate = "2019-04-10", 
        divAmt = 0.19, nextErn = "0000-00-00", nextErnTod = 1630L, 
        lastErn = "2018-12-17", lastErnTod = 3L, absAvgErnMv = 4.9379, 
        impliedIee = 4L, daysToNextErn = 0L, tkOver = 0L, etfIncl = "", 
        bestEtf = "XLK", sectorName = "Software & Services", 
        correlSpy1m = 0.82, correlSpy1y = 0.83, correlEtf1m = 0.89, 
        correlEtf1y = 0.81, beta1m = 0.18, beta1y = 0.11, ivPctile1m = 41L, 
        ivPctile1y = 25L, ivPctileSpy = 43L, ivPctileEtf = 63L, 
        ivStdvMean = -0.52, ivStdv1y = 3.73, ivSpyRatio = 1.44, 
        ivSpyRatioAvg1m = 1.33, ivSpyRatioAvg1y = 1.34, ivSpyRatioStdv1y = 4.46, 
        ivEtfRatio = 1.11, ivEtfRatioAvg1m = 1.01, ivEtfRatioAvg1y = 1L, 
        ivEtFratioStdv1y = 3.69, ivHvXernRatio = 1.2, ivHvXernRatio1m = 1.05, 
        ivHvXernRatio1y = 0.78, ivHvXernRatioStdv1y = 2.6, etfIvHvXernRatio = 0.93, 
        etfIvHvXernRatio1m = 1.04, etfIvHvXernRatio1y = 1.04, 
        etfIvHvXernRatioStdv1y = 0.07, slopepctile = 68.65, slopeavg1m = 3.68, 
        slopeavg1y = 3.48, slopeStdv1y = 0.67, etfSlopeRatio = 0.5, 
        etfSlopeRatioAvg1m = 0.49, etfSlopeRatioAvg1y = 0.46, 
        etfSlopeRatioAvgStdv1y = 0.09, impliedR2 = 0.4324, contango = 0.197222479619086, 
        nextDiv = 0.19, impliedNextDiv = 0.0843681, annActDiv = 0.76, 
        annIdiv = 0.506774, borrow30 = 1.57984048128128, borrow2yr = 2.21292357891798, 
        error = 0.0283262081211433, confidence = 90.6758487224579, 
        updatedAt = "2019-03-01 15:07:09")), included = list(
    list(type = list("earn"), data = list(list(ticker = "ORCL", 
        tradeDate = "2019-03-01", pxCls = 52.13, wksNextErn = 2L, 
        nextErnTod = 1630L, ernMnth = 3L, avgOptVolu20d = 15393L, 
        oi = 366521L, atmIvM1 = 15.5408, dtExM1 = 15L, atmIvM2 = 18.764, 
        dtExm2 = 78L, atmIvM3 = 19.6595, dtExM3 = 113L, atmIvM4 = 19.3808, 
        dtExM4 = 204L, straPxM1 = 1.39, straPxM2 = 3.79, smoothStraPxM1 = 1.33, 
        smoothStrPxM2 = 3.7, fcstStraPxM1 = 1.42, fcstStraPxM2 = 3.4, 
        loStrikeM1 = 52.5, hiStrikeM1 = 52.5, loStrikeM2 = 52.5, 
        hiStrikeM2 = 52.5, ernDate1 = "12/17/2018", ernDate2 = "9/17/2018", 
        ernDate3 = "6/19/2018", ernDate4 = "3/19/2018", ernDate5 = "12/14/2017", 
        ernDate6 = "9/14/2017", ernDate7 = "6/21/2017", ernDate8 = "3/15/2017", 
        ernDate9 = "12/15/2016", ernDate10 = "9/15/2016", ernDate11 = "6/16/2016", 
        ernDate12 = "3/15/2016", ernMv1 = 0.2624, ernMv2 = -0.305, 
        ernMv3 = -7.4562, ernMv4 = -9.4322, ernMv5 = -3.7657, 
        ernMv6 = -7.6719, ernMv7 = 8.569, ernMv8 = 6.2253, ernMv9 = -4.3074, 
        ernMv10 = -4.7479, ernMv11 = 2.6915, ernMv12 = 3.8203, 
        ernStraPct1 = 6.2487, ernStraPct2 = 5.5228, ernStraPct3 = 6.2863, 
        ernStraPct4 = 6.0248, ernStraPct5 = 4.7448, ernStraPct6 = 5.0436, 
        ernStraPct7 = 5.5556, ernStraPct8 = 3.7418, ernStraPct9 = 3.8856, 
        ernStraPct10 = 4.3435, ernStraPct11 = 4.7371, ernStraPct12 = 4.8554, 
        ernEffct1 = 1.7379, ernEffct2 = 1.7423, ernEffct3 = 3.2858, 
        ernEffct4 = 3.384, ernEffct5 = 1.9318, ernEffct6 = 3.256, 
        ernEffct7 = 3.5772, ernEffct8 = 3.1876, ernEffct9 = 2.3588, 
        ernEffct10 = 2.4699, ernEffct11 = 1.4884, ernEffct12 = 1.8712, 
        orHv5d = 10L, orHv10d = 12.71, orHv20d = 14.46, orHv60d = 27.63, 
        orHv90d = 27.37, orHv120d = 26.23, orHv252d = 24.55, 
        orHv500d = 21.9, orHv1000d = 20.98, orHvXern5d = 10L, 
        orHvXern10d = 12.71, orHvXern20d = 14.46, orHvXern60d = 26.51, 
        orHvXern90d = 26.63, orHvXern120d = 25.5, orHvXern252d = 22.79, 
        orHvXern500d = 19.96, orHvXern1000d = 19.53, clsHv5d = 6.87, 
        clsHv10d = 7.05, clsHv20d = 11.41, clsHv60d = 24.43, 
        clsHv90d = 25.01, clsHv120d = 23.75, clsHv252d = 24.19, 
        clsHv500d = 22.22, clsHv1000d = 21.11, clsHvXern5d = 6.87, 
        clsHvXern10d = 7.05, clsHvXern20d = 11.41, clsHvXern60d = 24.47, 
        clsHvXern90d = 25.07, clsHvXern120d = 23.97, clsHvXern252d = 21.16, 
        clsHvXern500d = 18.28, clsHvXern1000d = 18.4, iv10d = 14.7, 
        iv20d = 23.41, iv30d = 23.5, iv60d = 20.01, iv90d = 19.09, 
        iv6m = 19.45, iv1yr = 20.1, orIvXern20d = 16.53, orIvXernInf = 14.56, 
        slope = 3.887, fcstSlope = 4.3253, fcstErnEffct = 2.1897, 
        absAvgErnMv = 4.9379, ernMvStdv = 2.8909, impliedEe = 4L, 
        impErnMv = 5.64, impMth2ErnMv = 5.64, fairVol90d = 26.2747, 
        fairXieeVol90d = 25.1307, fairMth2XieeVol90d = 16.6156, 
        impErnMv90d = 8.78, impErnMvMth290d = 7.04, exErnIv10d = 14.7, 
        exErnIv20d = 17.22, exErnIv30d = 16.87, exErnIv60d = 16.12, 
        exErnIv90d = 15.88, exErnIv6m = 17.59, exErnIv1yr = 17.3, 
        updatedAt = "2019-03-01 03:07:09"))))))
```

What I am trying to do is put the list into a data frame.
Right now I am using the code;

```
library(tidyverse)
new.data = map_dfr(data, ~ bind_cols(flatten(.x)))
```

Column 155 is still a list. 
I would like the jumbled up column to be put into each of their individual columns. Thank you
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to again deploy `flatten` just on the 155th col, but then `cbind.data.frame` the first 154 columns to that result:

```
 really.new.data <- cbind(new.data[1:154], flatten(new.data[155]))
 str(really.new.data)
 #--------
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  714 variables:
 $ ticker                : chr  "MS" "GS" "MPC" "ORCL"
 $ tradeDate             : chr  "2019-03-01" "2019-03-01" "2019-03-01" "2019-03-01"
 $ assetType             : int  3 3 3 3
 $ priorCls              : num  42 196.7 62 52.1
 $ pxAtmIv               : num  42.6 198.4 62.5 52.6
 $ mktCap                : int  73261 73803 43158 217909
 $ cVolu                 : int  24699 28845 9612 17659
 #----------- snipped-----
```